# Feed for YouTube Subscription Collection

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am using YouTube's new "Subscription Collection" feature: it works great and is exactly what I'm looking for: the complete list of videos for a subset of my subscriptions.

Now I would like to get this list of videos through the API.

To be clear: **I do NOT want the list of subscriptions.  I want the videos in those subscriptions.**

For example, [this](https://www.youtube.com/feed/SC_UTvrZiAFn15oo_cbTh1dwbAO3TvnqcCcKz6bj8qHAPg) is the HTML page with the list of videos.  It is public, so anyone can access them.

Normally the URLs for getting via a video list through the API look like [this](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/FCWTJrGolf/favorites?v=2).

I've tried different ways of replacing "favorites" or "top_rated" with my collection id, but couldn't get any to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the Channel ID for the subscription/channel your interested in getting.

Then if your using Version 3 of the API you can use 'youtube.search.list' with the following parameters

part: snippet

channelId: [Channel your interested in]

type:video

This will get you the videos in that channel. If your using V2 I think you can use the users feed

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{userName/ChannelID}/uploads